# C++ Static function variable

Tags: c++, static-methods

In one of my methods, a function with two parameters is passed, and saved as rightClick. However, because its in a static function, the compiler wants the function to be initialised before. How can i go about this?

Mouse.cpp

```
void Mouse::clicked(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if(button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) {
        if(state == GLUT_DOWN) {
            isDragging = true;
            CurrentX = x;
            CurrentY = y;
        }
        else
        {
            isDragging = false;
        }
    }
    else if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON)
    {
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
        {
            isDragging = true;
            rightClick(x,y);
        }
    }

}

void Mouse::setRightClickFunction(void (*func)(int, int))
{
    rightClick = func;
}
```

The setRightClickFunction is called before click ever is. Except now i'm getting a different problem : "Mouse::rightClick", referenced from:
           Mouse::clicked(int, int, int, int) in Mouse.o

Comment: Do you mean that `setRightClickFunction` is static and if so, why? If not, what function does the compiler wants initialized, exactly?

Comment: Pass a valid function (global, in namespace, or static member function) as argument to the `setRightClickFunction` function, before the `clicked` handler is called.

Comment: You might also want to read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: Can you provide the exact compiler error?

Comment: Crystal ball guess: are you talking about `rightClick` being a static data member (not function) of the class `Mouse` and the linker (not compiler) complaining about undefined reference to `Mouse::rightClick`?

Comment: @Angew That is probably it, i havent done anything to do with passing functions as arguments before. Whats the correct way of doing that then?

Comment: Put this line `void (*Mouse::rightClick)(int, int) = 0;` in Mouse.cpp, `Mouse::rightClick` is (in effect) a global variable, you have to define it like you would any global variable.

Comment: Put that as an answer @john, that was it exactly. I just couldnt work out what to put in the various brackets.

Comment: @DuskFall a typedef would simplify things. I'll leave Angew to write up the answer if he want's, he would have told you the same thing.

Comment: @john Thanks, I appreciate that. And you're 100% coorect about the typedef, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, you're getting a linker error about "undefined reference to `Mouse::rightClick`. This has nothing to do with function pointers. It's just that whenever you declare a static data member in a class, it's only a declaration. You have to define it somewhere (= in exactly one .cpp file).

Assuming your class `Mouse` looks something like this:

```
class Mouse
{
  //...
  static void (*rightClick)(int, int);
  //...
};
```

You should put this line somewhere into `Mouse.cpp`:

```
void (*Mouse::rightClick)(int, int) = 0;
```

That will serve as the definition of the static data member `rightClick`.